# No module named 'MySQLdb' in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy

this is my lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
    data = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
    
    engine = create_engine('mysql://admin:blabla@database-1.blabla.eu-west 1.rds.amazonaws.com/blablabla')

    df.to_sql('list_last_update_lambda', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
    
    return()
```

Two layers installed:

[image]

log:

"errorMessage": "No module named 'MySQLdb'",
"errorType": "ModuleNotFoundError"

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: What is the FULL error msg? Where exactly are you using `MySQLdb`?

Comment: sorry I do not understand your question. The script works fine in Jupyter Notebook, and the rest of the error msg is irrelevant.

Comment: It is relevant. It shows exactly the line and full stack trace where the error originates.

Comment: looks like the mysql-python dependency is missing, try to add to your zip, or create a layer and use that as the layer check this link https://github.com/nonbeing/mysqlclient-python3-aws-lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
    data = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
    
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://admin:blabla@database-1.blabla.eu-west 1.rds.amazonaws.com/blablabla')

    df.to_sql('list_last_update_lambda', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
    
    return()
```